# Folders wont remove from finder sidebar (El capitan bug)

Tags: finder

I have a folder in my finder sidebar under favourites.

I moved, then also renamed, the folder that points to (without removing it from the finder sidebar).

Now I want to remove it from finder favourites (via right click, remove from sidebar), but finder won't let me, this seems to be disabled.  What should I do?

Hmmm...  I just tried to remove a folder that I hadn't removed or renamed, and the situation is the same.

Comment: What OS version?

Comment: El Cap - note issue is solved as below answer, albeit without pinpointing the cause.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22175 says "Remove an item: Drag the item icon out of the sidebar until you see a gray remove sign (x)."

Comment: I saw that but my point was that all the usual methods were not functioning (it wasn't a 'how to do it' question, but a 'something is not working in the os as it should', i.e., an os bug question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me was going to finder/preferences/sidebar, and unchecking then re-checking my user name folder (the offending folders did not appear there), which had the effect of making the offending folders disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences under the Finder menu. This brings up a window with a tab for the sidebar. From there you should be able to uncheck the folder you don't want to be displayed.

Comment: I tried that before but the offending folder (one of my own folders, not a standard system folder) doesn't appear there.  *However*, I simply clicked a few times to uncheck and check and toggling my own home folder has had the result of making the folders I had previously tried to remove but did not remove, now disappear. :)